# On Blogger Notable, instead of the Snippet, putting the read more in the jump link

Tags: blogger

I'm currently editing Notable template to apply it on my Blogger blog, but I wanted the post area to be more like Travel templates, where the post breaks is defined by the code on the post.

On Notable, there's a snippet that's not customizable by the user, and I wanted to know if there's a way to change it. I've tried the one solution for Contempo template developed dy Muhammad Saleh, but, on Notable, it shows the full post and ignores the "Read More".

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need more details. The link for my Testing Blog, where I applied Notable, is https://justtestand.blogspot.com/ (don't mind the content, it's 100% nonsense)